# BizTalk send port returns ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

Tags: oracle, wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have an application that inserts many rows into an Oracle database. The send port returns "ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation"

The send port is "WCF-Custom" using OracleDbBinding for the connection to the database.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in the past. My problem was using "WCF-Custom" port with OracleDBBinding to invoke an Oracle PL. That PL was very slow in their response and finally I received the error "ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation".

My issue was resolved changing the PL. I think that the error was produced by the "ReceiveTimeout" property of the Send Port. This property says that "Specifies the WCF message receive timeout. Essentially, this means the maximum amount of time the adapter waits for an inbound message.", I suspect that when ReceiveTimeout is accomplished, the WCF-Custom cancels the operation and then Oracle sends the error.

Answer (score 0):

**What's happening**:

When inserting large numbers of records WCF makes several parallel requests to insert the data. The default 'UseAmbientTransaction' setting wraps all the inserts within a single transaction. If one of the inserted rows breaks a database constraint it tries to rollback the transaction for all the inserts. The transactions all return the oracle 1013 exception and the real cause of the failure is lost.

**Solution**:

On the send port 'Transport Advanced Options' tab set the 'Ordered Delivery' check box. This prevents the parallel insert operations and the real cause of the error will be logged.

Comment: You start talking about the UseAmbientTransaction, but then you say the solution is Ordered Delivery. That doesn't seem right.  Ordered delivery just means that it delivers one message at a time, not that in will not wrap a batch insert with a transaction.

Comment: You're correct ordered delivery prevents multiple messages from occurring at the same time. A database error, with multiple processes, and ambient transaction is why you can't see the real issue. This error prevents you from seeing the root cause